# Use different Java version to import Gradle project in nvim

Tags: java, gradle, ide, neovim

I'm trying to use NeoVim for an older Java project that still uses Gradle (Wrapper) 6.8.3. As Gradle 6.8.3 is not compatible with Java 17 but Java 17 is needed to run `jdtls` I get this error in the log:

```
Can't use Java 17.0.6 and Gradle 6.8.3 to import Gradle project webapp.
```

Because of that I don't get auto complete etc.

I configured another Java runtime like that

```
    settings = {
        java = {
            configuration = {
                runtimes = {
                    {
                        name = 'JavaSE-1.8',
                        path = '/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0/',
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

but that didn't have any effect (still the error about Java 17). Do I have to configure somewhere/somehow that this runtime should be used to import the Gradle project?

Comment: The easiest option would be to update your Gradle version...

Comment: Sadly no. New Gradle requires new flyway (among others) requires new MySQL server (among others) etc. As it is only a maintenance project in that case the easiest solution would be not to use NeoVim if it does not work that way.

Comment: Perhaps you can extract whatever `jdtls` is doing to an external process, that you can call from Gradle? Gradle 6 isn't going to run with Java 17, it's just not [compatible](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html).

Comment: Yes I know. But isn't that what the runtimes are for? I thought the Java version of jdtls can be different from the one the project is using. Otherwise that would be quite a big limitation.

Comment: It seems that setting a default runtime (by adding `default = true,`) seems to solve the problem. So I guess that there is some kind of option to set the runtime to be used on a project level (don't know how) but as I'm missing that setting the default works.